# download pdf in laravel is giving error with different symbols instead of just downloading the file

Tags: laravel

Controller: this code was working before but it is giving error suddenly.

```
public function downloadProduct($id)
{


    if (Product::where('id', $id)->exists())
    {
        $data = Product::where('id', $id)->first();
        $file = public_path() . "/frontend/images/" . $data->file;
        if ($file) {
            return Response::download($file);
        }


    } else {
        abort(404);
    }

}
```

Error:

```
[REQ_ERR: COULDNT_RESOLVE_HOST] [KTrafficClient] Something is wrong. Enable debug mode to see the reason.%PDF-1.7 %���� 1 0 obj <>/Metadata 398 0
R/ViewerPreferences 399 0 R>> endobj 2 0 obj <> endobj 3 0 obj <>/ExtGState<>/ProcSet[/PDF/Text/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI] >>/MediaBox[ 0 0 612 792] /Contents 4 0
R/Group<>/Tabs/S/StructParents 0>> endobj 4 0 obj <> stream x��<�rܶ���?�m��
```

and many more lines similar to above line

What I've tried:
I tried to use response()->download() with headers as well but same issue

```
$headers = array(
  'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
);

return response()->download($file, $data->file, $headers);
```

composer.json

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^5.4.0"
},
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give an example for the filename (`$data->file`)?
The laravel docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#file-downloads explicitly states the following warning: 
_"Symfony HttpFoundation, which manages file downloads, requires the file being downloaded to have an ASCII file name."_

Comment: @Tschitsch    CalamusTDS.pdf

Comment: @Tschitsch is there smth wrong with the file name? It was working few months back.